# Need to create a ksh script for transferring files between application server and db server

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a requirement where i need to automate the transfer of a particular file from one location in the application server to the database server.

I can do it manually by using these steps but i need it in the script

```
#! /bin/ksh

directory path where the file need to be

ftp (hostname of the application server)

 username

 password

file location in the apps server

get filename

quit
```

Any help is Really appreciated....

Regards
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have just searched it:

```
ftp -inv <<EOF
   open app.server.address
   user username password
   cd some/location
   get filename
   bye
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ....I am new to the shell scripts sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

[Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) is a great tool for scripting such scenarios:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn ftp ftp.ftpsite.com 
expect "ftp> " 
send -- "user MYUSER\r" 
expect "Password: " 
send -- "MYPASSWORD\r" 
expect "ftp> " 
send -- "cd /pub/test\r" 
expect "ftp> " 
send -- "put myfile\r" 
expect "File transfered" 
send -- "exit\r"
```